# How do I make an effect dependent on two events in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a website with a footer that expands when the mouse hovers over it and shrinks when the mouse leaves. Original code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("footer").mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).animate( {"height": "10%", "opacity": 0.7} , 300 );
    });
    $("footer").mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).animate( {"height": "5%", "opacity": 0.3} , 300 );
    });
});
```

However, I now want to prevent the footer shrinking when the user only leaves from below i.e. just leaves the browser window. Is there someway of incorporating something along the lines of `&&mouseup()` into `$("footer").mouseleave(function() { ... });` so that the footer can only contract when the user leaves by the top?

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("footer").mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).animate( {"height": "10%", "opacity": 0.7} , 300 );
    });
    $("footer") /*code that I need */ function() {
        $(this).animate( {"height": "5%", "opacity": 0.3}, 300 );
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE (**M**inimal, **C**omplete, and **V**erifiable **E**xample)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: The function you give to `mouseleave` takes a jQuery event object that has `clientX` and `clientY` fields, but these tell you where the pointer was at the time the browser fired the event and checked the position of the pointer, and these x,y values are relative to the entire DOM, not the element. It would take some math to figure out where the pointer exited the element relative to the `#footer` element.  But this solution does not work on touch based devices like phones or tablets.

Comment: in the `mouseLeave` event, look at the position of the mouse, if it is at the bottom of the box, don't shrink the box.

Comment: Why don't you just only reduce the footer's height back down when the mouse enters the body of the page? If you've styled the page in such a way there's an element relatively covering the remaining area that should work unless I'm missing your point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you're wanting the footer to grow once the user hovers over its initial state, and then stay that size until their mouse moves away from the footer, elsewhere on the page.

The other solutions seem convoluted if this is all you're trying to achieve.

Consider this HTML:

```
<header></header>
<div class="page-contents">
    <!-- stuff that makes this big -->
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

And this jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $footer = $("footer");
    // This will make the footer grow on enter
    $footer.mouseenter(function() {
        $footer.animate( {"height": "10%", "opacity": 0.7} , 300 );
    });
   // This will make the footer shrink to original (css defined) size
    $(".page-contents").mouseenter(function() {
        $footer.animate( {"height": "5%", "opacity": 0.3} , 300 );
    });
});
```

I think that would do what you're looking for.

Edit: just to point out, by assigning `$("footer")` to a variable, you cache it, which is good for performance. (This is just a good practice.)

Comment: Ah thanks! I added a `<main>` tag and used `.mouseenter()` with that, which has worked well. Good answer; the solution seems pretty simple now. I suppose I shouldn't work so late! Also, thank you for the variable advice.

Comment: You're very welcome mate. Glad it worked out for you! You strike me as an intelligent guy--web development is not easy and it does take a long time to gain the experience you need to approach a wide array of problems holistically. Stick at it and I'm sure you'll do well :)

Answer (score 0):

It's only a concept. If I understand correctly, you only want the footer to shrink when mouse leave the footer area from its top edge. In that case, you can add another transparent DIV on the top of the footer and given height 0.

1. When mouse enter the footer, increased footer height as you wished and also increase the height of the transparent DIV by 1px.
2. When mouse enter the transparent DIV, shrink the footer and set the height of the transparent DIV to 0px.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.footer').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).css('height', '10%');
     $('.footer .top_edge').css('height', '1px');
  });
  
  $('.footer .top_edge').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $('.footer').css('height', '5%');
    $('.footer .top_edge').css('height', '0');
  });
});
```

```css
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #91d895;
  height: 5%;
}

.footer > .wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.footer .top_edge {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="footer">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="top_edge"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```